# How to upgrade from Antlr4 4.2 (C#) to latest verion (4.4?)

Tags: antlr4

On the ANTLR download page it states that the latest version of ANTLR is 4.4. From the C# Target section on the same page, clicking "ANTLR 4 C# Target (Latest Release)" brings me to the 4.3 Target Release GitHub page that has a link for Readme.md, which when clicked, results in a 404.

Question 1: Although the download page states that the latest version for C# 4.4, the version I get via NuGet is 4.3. Does this mean 4.4 isn't available for C#?

Question 2: Where do I find the tools for code generation that correspond to the version I got from NuGet (that is, Antlr 4.3)?

We attempted using antlr-4.4-complete.jar for code generation - we substituted that jar for the previous (antlr4-csharp-4.0.1-SNAPSHOT-complete.jar) in our build script and now we get: "error(31):  ANTLR cannot generate CSharp_v4_5 code as of version 4.4" (which we didn't get previously). We also tried antlr-4.3-complete.jar and got similar results.

What do we need to take advantage of the latest release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I corrected the link to the Readme.md in the release notes. Thanks for pointing it out, although a more reliable way to notify the maintainer is to [file an issue directly for the project](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs/issues).

Second, the C# target is not based on the version of ANTLR posted on antlr.org, but instead on a fork of the project I created to optimize performance and (especially) memory overhead associated with parsing highly complex grammars. The tools use different serialization formats and are not interchangeable.

The C# code generator is distributed via NuGet, as described in the readme file.

ANTLR 4.4's primary differences over ANTLR 4.3 are the following:

1. Inclusion of additional targets (irrelevant for the C# target, since the runtime libraries are not C# and also use the other serialization format)
2. A bug-fix in the tool that has minimal effect on users (it throws an exception instead of reporting an error at code generation time for a specific type of grammar error)
3. Fixes a bug that occurs when an unknown target is specified (also not applicable to the C# target, since the MSBuild integration automatically selects the correct target language)

Based on this, the 4.3 release of the C# target is functionally equivalent to 4.4. I'm waiting to release a "4.4" version until I can address other performance concerns and functionality which doesn't apply to the reference version. In particular, I'm working on the following:

- Improving concurrency by reducing contention ([sharwell/antlr4#13](https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4/issues/13))
- Supporting indirect left recursion (currently a work-in-progress in the [indirect-lr](https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4/tree/indirect-lr) and [java8-grammar](https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4/tree/java8-grammar) branches)
- Supporting a new `baseContext` option, [shown here](https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4/commit/e9d248674b5ce75c43932b80d41beabff7ae4f12#diff-6) for a Java 8 grammar